# Phone calls to the past - The Long Game

Tags: plot-explanation, doctor-who

In the Doctor Who episode 'The Long Game' (Doctor Who 2005, Season 1, Episode 7), Adam makes multiple phone calls from the future back to his own time, leaving a message on his parents answering machine.

Is there something in the plot that explains how a phone call can be made through time and space to a distant point in the past?

Comment: Winston Churchill is also able to phone the Doctor where/whenever he is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It wasn't Earth tech. He used [Rose's cellphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Doctor_Who_items#Superphone) that was originally modified by the Doctor so that she could talk to her mother:

> The "Superphone" is an upgraded mobile phone that can make calls across time and space. It even calibrates to the user's home time period, as shown by Adam Mitchell's ability to call his home time on Rose Tyler's phone ("The Long Game"), despite their native time periods being about six years apart.
>   [...]
>   The superphone first appears in "The End of the World", where the Ninth Doctor modifies Rose's Nokia 3200 mobile phone with a special device that goes in place of the battery.

Comment: And, as the Doctor remarks after Rose makes her first call to the past, "Think that's amazing, you want to see the bill."